# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, парсинг ссылок

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Добрый день друзья, Помогите достать содержимое тега  а именно содержимое "rel" вот этот текст "/question/19613371282441896"

```php
foreach($html - > find('div[class=question-block clickable]') as $element) {
  $massiv[] = $element - > plaintext;

  // }
}
```

```html
<div id="user_responses">
  <div class="question-block clickable" rel="/question/19613371282441896">
```

Answer (score 1):

Все атрибуты **уже** содержатся в объекте `$element`. То есть вы можете получить атрибут `rel` с помощью `$element->rel`. Например:

```
foreach($html - > find('div[class=question-block clickable]') as $element) {
  $massiv[] = $element - > plaintext;
  $rel = $element->rel;
  // }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае, я бы использовал библиотеку [phpQuery](https://github.com/Coderockr/phpQuery). Она просто ставится с помощью [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/).

Допустим:

```
// У Вас есть такой  HTML "огрызок"
$html = '<div class="user id_1"><div class="question clickable" rel="/link/1"></div></div>';

// Инициализируем Singletone объект для работы с jQuery в PHP
$questionsDom = phpQuery::newDocument($html);

// Крутим все блоки с вопросами
foreach ($questionsDom->find('div.question.clickable') as $question){
  // Достаем rel аттрибут
  $rel = pq($question)->attr('rel');

  // Выводим результат
  print_r($rel);
}
```

***phpQuery*** использовать просто, так же как и нативный ***jQuery***